# Sending custom cookies (and viewing the ones set naturally) with Perl's WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, cookies, mechanize

I'm trying to scrape a particularly troublesome website. Though all the parameters match and the referrer matches, I see different results when perl runs it than when I watch dev tools.

When I do a copy-as-curl from dev tools, the only header I can't confirm as identical is `-H 'Cookie:` and its contents. Running that curl command gives me the proper results just as I receive in the browser.

So, what syntax do I use with WWW::Mechanize to set the cookie's value explicitly rather than letting Mechanize do it for me based on the past gets/posts?

Also, how can I view what it does want to set the cookie's value to?

Comment: Have you tried to change self-identification via `$mech->agent_alias( $alias )`?  IMHO it it is worth to be checked first.

Comment: Often the trick here is that the client is using JavaScript or loading some other resource to set the cookie. If you don't run the JavaScript or load every image (And so on), you don't get the cookie. Otherwise, WWW::Mechanize should manage cookies for you.

Comment: @briandfoy That was indeed the case. Javascript was loading the cookies, and so even though I was loading all the various page hits, the last one would be rejected. Still working through how to calculate the values but things look good now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To examine the cookies returned from a WWW::Mechanize request, use the following:

```
my $cookie_jar = $mech->cookie_jar; # returns a HTTP::Cookies object
print $cookie_jar->as_string, "\n”;
```

To set a cookie for use by WWW::Mechanize in requests, you would do the following:

```
$mech->cookie_jar->set_cookie(-name=>'YourCookieName',
                   -value=>'YourCookieValue',
                   -host=>'www.your website.com',
                   -expires=>'Sun, 31 Jan 2021 18:45:47 GMT',
                   -path=>'/'
                   -secure=>'false');
```

Refer to the HTTP::Cookies documentation for other useful methods.